# Do Oracle ManagedDataAccess Client Query in hosted VB script

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle

I'm trying to do an Oracle Query in a VB Scripted "field" inside a web application (the webapplication has a text field that apparently is interpreted as VBScript during further processing). I came as far as the following, but i'm missing e.g. how to instantiate the connection with the connectionstring.

```vb
'
' Load the Assembly
'
Dim oAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly
oAssembly = oAssembly.LoadFrom("E:\APPS\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll")
'
' Get Type Connection, create instance
'
Dim oType As System.Type
Dim DBConn As System.Object
oType = oAssembly.GetType("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection")
DBConn = Activator.CreateInstance(oType,connstr)
DBConn.Open()
'
'
'
```

So note stuff like createobject is not available here. Anyone have a clue on how to let's say get as far as opening the connection?

The on-line compilation gives me:

> "Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated. Variable declaration without an 'As' clause. Type of Object assumed."

update: hang on i think ive got it

Comment: This is not VBScript looks more like VB.Net

Comment: The connection string is accessible via  the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.ConnectionString property.